# Add item to Reading List in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to add an item/url to the Reading List in Safari from an app? I've looked around but I can only find information [how to add it manually](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tips-shortcuts/quick-tip-how-to-use-safaris-reading-list/). Is there really no way to realise this from code?

Comment: there is no Mobile Safari SDK available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `iOS 6.1` or lower there is no way for applications to add items to the reading list.

However, In `iOS 7.0` the `SafariServices` framework was added that does allow you do add items to the reading list:

```
#import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h> 
SSReadingList * readList = [SSReadingList defaultReadingList];
NSError * error = [NSError new];

BOOL status =[readList addReadingListItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlToAdd] title:titleToAdd previewText:previewText error:&error];

if(status)
{
        NSLog(@"Added URL");

}
else    NSLog(@"Error");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple (but only available for iOS 7 and greater) - checkout: http://hayageek.com/ios-safariservices-ssreadinglist/

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull about that iOS 10 has bug to add reading List with SSReadingList.